# How to detect a newline in a string in python 3 other than using the in operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Basically it's about a problem involving detecting comments in a C/C++/Java program.So single line comments continue until a newline arrives.I inputted the whole program as a text.Now i just can't figure out a way to copy the text to another variable until newline occurs using in operator.See my code for better understanding.

```
import sys
j=0
b=""
text = sys.stdin.read()
for i in range(len(text)):
    if text[i]=="/":
        j=i
        if text[i+1]=="*":
            while text[j]!="/":
                b=b+text[j]
        else:
            while a[j]!="\n":
                b=b+text[j]

print(b)
```

Comment: As currently stated this is a bit too broad a question. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

A carriage return character is a delimiter that indicates the end of stdin. That is the way it works. If you want to get the rest of input, you call input() again in python3.

Answer (score 0):

#### Single-line `//` Comments

If I understand it correctly, you want to extract all single-line C/C++/Java-style comments from a file.  Consider this sample file:

```
$ cat sample.c 
abc //comment1
def
hij //comment2
```

In python, use this code:

```
import re
with open('sample.c') as f:
    print(re.findall(r'//(.*)\n', f.read()))
```

This produces the output:

```
['comment1', 'comment2']
```

#### Single-line `//` or `/*...*/` Comments

As sample input, consider:

```
$ cat sample2.c
abc //comment1
def
hij //comment2
klm /* comment3 */
```

In python, use this code:

```
import re
with open('sample2.c') as f:
    print(re.findall(r'(?://|/\*)(.*?)(?:\*/|\n)', f.read()))
```

The sample output is:

```
['comment1', 'comment2', ' comment3 ']
```